# jqueryMobile misplaced icon image

Tags: jquery-mobile

In jquery mobile (v 1.1.1), I am consistently getting the buttons with data-iconpos="notext" rendered as shown in the image (the icon is not centered). [image: misaligned button in jquery mobile]

Any ideas on how to resolve this please?

Comment: It seems like there was a similar issue to this reported https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4227 and was caused due to CSS. I would suggest logging the bug with the jquery team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth at this late date, I've encountered this issue whenever I have a [ThemeRoller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php)-generated .css file with a version that's out of sync with my project's jQuery Mobile version.  Importing and updating the CSS in ThemeRoller with a matching jQuery Mobile version has always resolved the issue.